# How to edit .htaccess file to redirect www to non-www in apache/ubuntu server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I've got 2 .htaccess files on my server.  One of them is in my /www folder and the other is in my /www/new_site folder(I've got a main site and a dev/testing site).

In the /www/new_site .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

In the /www .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^www\.collegeconnect\.ph$
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://stage.collegeconnect.ph/$1 [R,L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

How do I edit both files so that the www version of the site redirects to the non-www version of the site?  Right now, the www leads to a server error.

Comment: How many answers to this question already exist on this site currently? 3459237294?

Comment: Sorry for the little pun :-) I suggest you take a look at those existing answers. They should help you to solve your issue. Just google "stackoverflow www to non-www" for a start ...

Comment: @arkascha yea, problem is my www is not redirecting.  Keeps saying "This site can't be reached." DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error.  I added a www A record into my DNS settings.

Comment: Ah, so you updated your question. Thanks.

Comment: That error message you mention here in the comments (why not in the question?) indicates an issue with your DNS setup. That has nothing to do with request rewriting. Maybe you just have to wait a few hours until the DNS change is propagated?

Comment: @arkascha yep, was a DNS issue.  though I still have to fix my htaccess file because the redirect isn't working the way I want it to but it is starting to work.  Had to make sure the DNS was fixed up in my CDN (Cloudflare).

Comment: And what does "is not working the way I want it to" actually mean _exactly_ ?

Comment: Oh, and just a side note: I really do hope that "I've got a main site and a dev/testing site" does _not_ mean that you are using your hosting provider as a "dev site".